# CSS - Use 1 image to many of them

Tags: html, css

In bootstrap.css, there is a main image where there are all the icons and stuff.

How can I use CSS to display an image in the "main image" ?

Would I use margin?

Answer (score 4):

That's called an image sprite. You display it as a background image and use background position to specify the area to be visible.

For example displaying an area that is 20x20 pixels at 40,100 in the image:

```
.myIcon {
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  background: url(spriteimage.png) -40px -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called a `CSS sprite` and you can access different images in the sprite by using the `background-position` property.

something like this,

```
background: url('main-sprite.png') -10px -10px;
```

where `-10px -10px` is the `x and y positions` of the image in the sprite.